# Where to find good resources to learn Events and EventListener in javascript and know more about it?

Tags: javascript

Where to find good resources to learn Events and EventListner in javascript and know more about it?

i want to know more about it form beginner to high level

Answer (score 2):

[QuirksMode.org](http://www.quirksmode.org/) is a great JavaScript resource; I recommend these pages to start learning about events:

1. [Introduction to Events](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/introevents.html).
2. [Advanced Event Registration Models](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_advanced.html).
3. [Event Compatibility Table](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/index.html).

Comment: @Buffon: sorry, I don't know of any videos.  You should consider "un-accepting" my answer as the solution and giving it a +1 instead so that others will see that the question is unanswered and perhaps post a link to a video?

Comment: sorry i "un-accepted" the answer but i will "re-accept" it if no other person answer me

Comment: @Buffon: no problem, hopefully someone else has some good resources.  Please consider pressing the "+1" (up arrow) button if you think my answer was helpful, doing so will indiciate to others that this is the sort of thing you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably the best video tutortial for javascript beginer:

```
http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/javascript-from-null-video-series/
```

When you understand a bit more about javscript and had made various js applications, I redcomend go back to QuirksMode.org for knowledge validation, QuirksMode.org is very well explained but it's no place for absolutely beginer.